# Select all elements within parent that have images

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, jquery-selectors

So I'm writing a jQuery plugin to apply retina graphics. I need to select an element (if it has a background image or a source image) and then every element inside of it (if it has a background image or a source image).

Here's my plugin:

```
//RetinizeJS
(function($){
    $.fn.retinize = function(){
    $(this).filter(function(){
        if (this.currentStyle) 
            return this.currentStyle['backgroundImage'] !== 'none';
        else if (window.getComputedStyle)
            return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(this,null)
                .getPropertyValue('background-image') !== 'none';
    }).addClass('bg_found');
    };
})(jQuery);

$('body').retinize();
```

That needs to return the body element if it has a background image, and all the elements within if they are `<img src="" />` or if they have a CSS `background-image` property.

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE 9:13 PM:

This doesn't add the class HAS_IMAGE to anything, and it still doesn't select the `<img>` elements if i remove `|| ($this.css('backgroundImage') !== 'none');`.

```
//RetinizeJS
    (function($){
        $.fn.retinize = function(){
            $this = $(this);
            $this.find('*').andSelf().filter(function(){
                return $this.is('img') || ($this.css('backgroundImage') !== 'none');
        }).addClass('HAS_IMAGE');
    };
    })(jQuery);

    $('body').retinize()
```

Comment: The conspiracy theorist in me is beginning to suspect that there's a downvoting bot about the past few days. I don't see why this would be downvoted.

Comment: Who downvoted it? It has no downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an element has a certain CSS rule value by using `.css()`. I'm thinking (i.e. not tested) that by checking `.css('backgroundImage')`, you should be able to check if an element has a background image, whether or not it was set using CSS `background` or CSS `background-image`.

You can use that knowledge to set up a filter function like so:

```
$(selector).filter(function () {
    var _this = $(this);
    return _this.is('img') || (_this.css('backgroundImage') !== 'none');
});
```

You'll just have to work on how that cascades into the descendants with your plugin.

However, if you're rigidly having to check *from `<body>`*, then extending `$.fn` sounds like the wrong way to go. `$.fn` extensions are meant for functions that act on a jQuery object, like `$('body').retinize()` or `$('div img').retinize()`.

You'd probably want to make that a utility function instead by extending directly into `$`, so you can call it via `$.retinize()` or something.

Comment: That's not the issue. I alreayd have code that filters out images. I ned to select an elements AS WELL AS its children. Like this: `$(this, this *)` but that doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, have you tried `$(this).find('*').andSelf()`? Doing the `.find('*')` *should* get you all descendants (for children, you just want `.children()`), then calling the `.andSelf()` adds back the parent container into the collection (i.e. children + parent).

Comment: Also, with your code from the answer, will that select elements with a background image in the shorthand as well?

Comment: Haven't tried, but it *should™*. From experience, it does, but that may be subject to browser nuances.

Comment: Just tested, it does, at least in every recent browser.

Comment: Also, your code isn't returning anything at all. I'll post what I have in the question in a sec. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, just pop a link or something. I'll take a look as soon as I can.

Comment: Figured it out. I was using _this elsewhere on the page. ;-)